# build a word processor with javascript

Tags: javascript

We are building a word processor and we would like to implement word wrapping functionality.

Given a maximum number of characters in a line followed by a list of words, return a collection of strings where each line contains as many words as possible concatenated by a space. The length of each string should not exceed the maximum length.

```
      function wrapLines(lineLength, words){
        for(var i<0; i<words.length; i++){
          if(word[i].length<=11){
            console.log(word[i]);
          }else if(word[i].length>11){


        }
       }
      }
     }
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is a code problem solving question and answer site. You suggested a goal but what's your specific problem and question?

Comment: I've started an open source project to build a word processor in Typescript, just announced it yesterday actually. It's still in very early phase with lots of bugs and things to reconsider/refactor, contributions are welcomed :) https://github.com/yuzhenmi/taleweaver